# Direct reply notification starts an activity

Tags: android, kotlin, android-notifications, android-8.0-oreo

I am trying to get the text typed on the direct reply. I can get the text but when click the send text button, it opens the activity that intent shows.

```
val resultIntent = Intent(this, MessagesActivity::class.java)
val stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(this)

stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent)

val resultPendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(
        this,
        0,
        resultIntent,
        PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
)
```

And here's Notification Builder

```
val mBuilder = Notification.Builder(this, id)
    .setContentTitle(data["title"])
    .setContentText(data["body"])
    .setLargeIcon(image)
    .addAction(action)
    .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.logo)
    .setAutoCancel(true)
```

I don't want it to open the activity. Also I tried to use a intent service, it does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using `PendingIntent.getActivity` which means you want to handle result from your operation on activity. It's logical that this activity need to start before proceeding. 
From documentation of `getActivity`:

> Retrieve a PendingIntent that will start a new activity, like calling
>   Context.startActivity(Intent). Note that the activity will be started
>   outside of the context of an existing activity, so you must use the
>   Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK launch flag in the Intent.

You need to use `PendingIntent.getBroadcast`.

For more information look [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getActivity(android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int))